# Change text in Textbox with button click?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm making an app that totals up results from a coin toss, and I'm having trouble changing the numbers in my textboxes, and I could use some help.

So, how could I go about this?

Here's my code:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int number = random.Next(1, 100);

        //debug_TB.Text = Convert.ToString(number);

        if (number <= 50)
        {
            yesornogrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            numberTot = numberTot + 1;
            numberYes = numberYes + 1;

            yes_total_TB.Text = 
        }
        else if (number >= 51)
        {
            yesornogrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            numberTot = numberTot + 1;
            numberNo = numberNo + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "`yes_total_TB.Text = `" looks like you're close - what do you want to put in that text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just something like this:

```
yes_total_TB.Text = string.Format("{0} YES of {1} tries", numberYes, numberTot);
```

and of course

```
no_total_TB.Text = string.Format("{0} NO of {1} tries", numberNo, numberTot);
```

**UPDATE**

In C# 6.0, this could be totally rewritten using [string interpolation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx)

```
yes_total_TB.Text = $"{numberYes} YES of {numberTot} tries";
no_total_TB.Text = $"{numberNo} NO of {numberTot} tries"
```